# How to crop image to text in Powerpoint?

Tags: text, powerpoint, crop

In Powerpoint (15.13.1 for Mac OS X) I can find the option to crop an image to a shape but I can't find how to crop it to text. Can anyone enlighten me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's PowerPoint 2010, 2013 and 2016 but no 2015.  Which do you have?

There's no way I know to crop a picture to text, but you can fake it.  In (as I recall) PPT 2013 or maybe 2010 and later you can do this:

Insert a picture and send it behind the text you want to fill with a picture.

Select the picture then hold down Ctrl while you click the text to select it too.  It has to be done in this order or it won't work.

Under Drawing Tools, the Format tab, Insert Shapes group, click Merge Shapes and choose Intersect.

Another trick is to intersect the text with a plain rectangle. This converts the text to a shape that can be filled with a picture.

Comment: I have PowerPoint 15.13.1 for Mac OS X. Your solution is interesting (I didn't know the group shape option). However, PowerPoint subtracts the text box (rectangle) but not the actual text.

Comment: If you found the Merge Shapes option in Mac PPT, point me at it ... I'm having no luck finding it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. When you select the picture then the text (⌘ + click), the "Shape Format" tab appears. Inside of it, to the right of the "Text Box" button you will find a small icon with two overlapping circles. That's the "group shape" I guess, since it contains the "Union", "Combine", "Fragment", "Intersect" and "Subtract" features. Do you see it ?

Comment: Bingo.  Thanks!  I'd missed the fact that you use PPT 2016.  The feature's not in 2011.  Found it in 2016.  And it works as I described here.  I wonder if this is one of those things that's been fixed in an update.  Hm.  Or broken.

Comment: Yep, never mind, works like a charm, thanks so much ! I don't know what I was doing wrong ! A thousand thanks for your help :)